# Permiso denegado al extraer documento en zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando extraer unos documentos de un zip y tengo el siguiente error. La carpeta tiene todos los permisos si lo hago manual la extraccion funciona.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'D:\requestsOSM\descargaPOI'

el codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
filezip = r'D:\requestsOSM\descargaPOI'

fileout = r'D:\requestsOSM\descargaPOI\ExtraccionPOI'

with zipfile.ZipFile(filezip, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(fileout)
```

Probe ejecutando visual code como administrador y tengo el mismo inconveniente.

Comment: Hola. Al parecer estás tratando de abrir una carpeta, lo que tienes que hacer es abrir archivos.

Comment: La variable `filezip` no parece tener un nombre de archivo válido ¿no debería terminar `.zip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a los comentarios:
filezip debe ser un archivo zip, mientras que fileput, la ruta de destino.

```
import zipfile

filezip = r'D:/requestsOSM/descargaPOI/prueba.zip'
fileout = r'D:/requestsOSM/descargaPOI/ExtraccionPOI/'

with zipfile.ZipFile(filezip, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(fileout)
```